# Can apple cider vinegar be substitute when coloring eggs?

Tags: eggs

I have egg coloring kit that suggested using vinegar for darker colors. Only have apple cider vinegar in cupboard. Can I use this instead or am I better off just using water?

Answer (score 9):

Apple cider vinegar still contains the acidity that the dye needs to activate, so it should work just fine. You may encounter a slight discoloration due to the naturally brown tint of apple cider vinegar.

Answer (score 2):

Apple cider vinegar worked fine with no coloring issues either.